# Asterisk 16.30.0 running in EC2 connected with sip.js client no audio during call

Tags: amazon-ec2, asterisk, sip, jssip, sipjs

I am having `Asterisk 16.30.0` installation in a EC2 instance.
Asterisk is installed using https://linuxhint.com/install-asterisk-ubuntu-22-04/

Below is the configuration for my Asterisk server running in EC2.

---

http.conf

```
[general]
enabled=yes
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=8088
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:8089
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
```

---

sip.conf

```
[general]
tcpenable=yes
udpenable=yes
tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=5060
realm=127.0.0.1 ; replaced with static IP of EC2
transport=ws,wss
nat=yes
externip=127.0.0.1 ; replaced with static IP of EC2
media_address=127.0.0.1 ; replaced with static IP of EC2
directmedia=no
dtlsenable=yes
webrtc=yes
dtlssetup=actpass
rtcp_mux=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw,alaw

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
transport=ws,wss
tcpenable=yes
nat=yes
avpf=yes
force_avp=yes
directmedia=no
qualify=yes
icesupport=yes
encryption=yes
dtlsenable=yes
dtlscipher=ALL
dtlsverify=fingerprint
dtlsverify=no
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
dtlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
dtlssetup=actpass
rtcp_mux=yes
disallow=all
allow=alaw,ulaw

[1000](friends_internal)
username=1000
callerid=1000
secret=somepass

[2000](friends_internal)
username=2000
callerid=2000
secret=somepass
```

---

extension.conf

```
[default]
exten => 1000,1,Dial(SIP/1000)
exten => 2000,1,Dial(SIP/2000)
```

---

rtp.conf

```
[general]
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
icesupport=yes
stunaddr=stun.l.google.com:19302
turnaddr=turn:myturnserver
turnusername=username
turnpassword=pass
```

The required keys are generated using the command.

```
./ast_tls_cert -C ec2-ip -O "ec2-ip" -d /etc/asterisk/keys    

Required access provided to asterisk user to access keys.
```

---

The `sip.js 0.16.0` client application running in a Google Chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="https://sipjs.com/download/sip-0.16.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function sipTest() {
     const userUri = SIP.UserAgent.makeURI("sip:1000@ec2-static-ip");
     const userAgent = new SIP.UserAgent({
        uri: userUri,
        logLevel: "debug",
        authorizationPassword: somepass,
        authorizationUsername: '1000',
        rel100: false,
        hackViaTcp: false,
        hackIpInContact: true,
        hackWssInTransport: false,
        transportOptions: {
          traceSip: true,
          server: "wss://ec2-static-ip:8089/ws"
        },
        delegate: {
          onInvite,
          onConnect,
          onDisconnect
        },
        sessionDescriptionHandlerFactoryOptions: {
          constraints: {
            audio: true,
            video: false
          },
          peerConnectionOptions: {
            rtcConfiguration: {
              iceServers: [
                {
                  urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
                },
                {
                  urls: "turn:myturn-server",
                  username: "username",
                  credential: "password",
                }
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      });
      const registerer = new SIP.Registerer(userAgent);

      userAgent.start().then(() => {
        console.log('UserAgent: start');
        registerer.register();
      });

      // Setup myRegisterer state change handler
      registerer.stateChange.addListener((newState) => {
        switch (newState) {
          case SIP.RegistererState.Registered:
            console.log('Registered...');
            break;
          case SIP.RegistererState.Unregistered:
            console.log('Unregistered...');
            break;
          case SIP.RegistererState.Terminated:
          console.log('Terminated...');
            break;
         }
     });

     function onInvite(invitation) {
       console.log('onInvite: invitation: ', invitation);
       const callSession = invitation;

       // Setup session state change handler
       callSession.stateChange.addListener((state) => {
         switch (state) {
           case SIP.SessionState.Initial:
             console.log('SessionState.Initial');
             break;
           case SIP.SessionState.Establishing:
             console.log('SessionState.Establishing');
             break;
          case SIP.SessionState.Established:
            console.log('SessionState.Established');

            // We need to check the peer connection to determine which track was added
            var pc = callSession.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection;
            console.log('PC: ', pc); // Valid
            console.log('PC getReceivers: ', pc.getReceivers()); // Empty
            console.log('PC getRemoteStreams: ', pc.getRemoteStreams()); // Empty

            // Gets remote tracks
            var remoteStream = new MediaStream();
            pc.getReceivers().forEach(function(receiver) {
              if (receiver.track) {
                remoteStream.addTrack(receiver.track);
              }
            });

            // I did try both the ways 
            const remoteAudio = new Audio();
            // const remoteAudio = document.getElementById('remoteAudio');

            remoteAudio.srcObject = remoteStream;
            remoteAudio.play();

            break;
          case SIP.SessionState.Terminating:
          case SIP.SessionState.Terminated:
            console.log('SessionState.Terminated');
            break;
          default:
            debugOut("Unknown session state.");
        }
      });

      invitation.accept();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="sipTest()">
  <audio id="remoteAudio"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

**Issues I am facing:**
No audio is heard on both the ends.

> On the client side:

```
When call is in SessionState.Established I get `pc.getRemoteStreams()` as empty and also `pc.getReceivers()` is empty in the Sip.js client.  
And because of that I am not able to add streams to the Audio element.
```

> On the server, I get below error after call is connected.

```
**When call is established and connected:**    
WARNING[84463] chan_sip.c: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx for seqno 123456789 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 31999ms with no response
WARNING[84463] chan_sip.c: Hanging up call xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).

**Also below errors:**   
ERROR[92854] chan_sip.c: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data
ERROR[92854] chan_sip.c: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data
ERROR[92854] chan_sip.c: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data
ERROR[92854] chan_sip.c: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data
```

I have tested the stun and turn serves and they are appropriate resolution and I get relay server IP. Also EC2 instance security group provides access to all the UDP and TCP ports. For testing I have accepted the self signed certificate in using HTTPS Url from the browser where client app is running.

Comment: This is a network issue, not a programming one. Enabling SIP debug will show you SDP and might provide some more insight into what's happening. Why are you using Asterisk 16, and the old deprecated chan_sip driver?

Comment: Thanks, I will use latest Asterisk. Is the pj sip latest to be used? I did debug the sip logs but did not found any thing serious that can cause the issue.

Comment: chan_sip has been removed from modern versions of Asterisk and has been deprecated almost ten years. So yes, chan_pjsip is what you should be using. As I said, this is not a programming issue but a network connectivity problem and is better dealt with at [sf] after you do some basic troubleshooting. Did you try connecting another client to your Asterisk instance?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 service is NATed service, you have private IP.

So if you have any issues with sound, you should ensure you have setuped external IP correctly and RTP ports(10000-20000 usually) are open in amazon firewall.

For see exact issue do

```
asterisk -r
pjsip set logger on
sip set debug on
rtp set debug on
```

ps nat=yes is not correct for asterisk 1.8+. Use nat=force_rport,comedia